# Get Midi file time

Tags: c, midi

I'm trying to read a raw MIDI file.

My question is, if I have, for instance, e MIDI with 36 seconds length of my WMplayer, how can I get the same time by performing calculation with MIDI info.

In this file, I have:

```
        ticks per 1/4               : 192
        delta time total            : 13822
        no tempo info so, (I guess) : 500 micro s per 1/4
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Already figured it out!

to get you time (milliseconds) per tick, 500/192 ~ 2.6

to get the time of the track simply, 2.6(time per tick) * (total of delta times) = 35.9 ~ 36''

Thanks